# HTACCESS Forzar Redireción parcial a 404 por ataque

Tags: .htaccess

Muy buenas, fuí atacado en mi web y se generaron redirecciones hacia sitios maliciosos.
Ya limpié todo pero sigo saliendo en el SERP de Google y para hacerlo tengo que generar errores 404 para las rutas afectadas. Así dice Google que es el primer paso para desaparecer de la búsqueda.
Ahora los enlaces que surgen desde el SERP de Google dirigen ya a mi web pero quiero que generen lancen 404.

Todos los enlaces son del tipo:

```
http://misitioweb.com/?bezstywue=un-monton-de-parametros1

http://misitioweb.com/?bezstywue=un-monton-de-parametros2

http://misitioweb.com/?bezstywue=un-monton-de-parametros3
```

Yo quiero hacer que todo lo que empiece por

```
 http://misitioweb.com/?bezstywue
```

genere error 404
He probado cosas como

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^\?bezstywue(.*)$
```

Pero no me funciona.
¿Podeis ayudarme?
Gracias un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al final lo solucioné con:

```
 RewriteEngine ON
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bezstywue
 RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, te ganara unos puntos y adicional unas medallas

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que tengas mal puesta la barra lateral, tu tienes esto:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^\?bezstywue(.*)$
```

Y quizá deberias poner esto:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/?bezstywue(.*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso este siguiente código, quizás te pueda servir.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error-404.php
RewriteRule ^error-404/$ error-404.php [L]
```

También prueba en usar los parámetros al revés ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^/?bezstywue(.*)$ error-404.php [L,R=301]
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas.